# Short initiation for lazy colleagues

Tags: requirements, prince2, initiation

Last summer I finished a PBA in Software Development.
and got hired into a Company with a small IT department.
(8 Guys.. 4 developers)

We make inhouse solutions, from services to websites or small applications.
These four developers are working kinda rogue.

What would usually happen is a guy from the legal department wants a small app that can do something, like sort our legal documents.
So he grabs a developer. they talk about it, and the developer does it.

Then we have experienced some issues like these:

> 1: A boss somewhere determinds we don't need the program anyway
>
> 2: It takes a lot longer to make, or is more complicated
>
> 3: The developer and the user don't agree on the result

So my boss asked me to create a standard way for us to project initiate, to avoid these Things. (I've been taught Prince2 and SCRUM)
But here is the problem.

If I make them fill out project initiation documents, with full buisness case and risk analysis etc. they simple won't do it.

So I need a compressed version, and that is why I'm here
I'm here to ask, for creating smaller sites and applications, what is the core data you need before starting.

I was thinking something like this:

> 1: Owner: WHO is responsible and WHO decides outside IT
>
> 2: Buisiness Case Description: Why are we making it?
>
> 3: timetable
>
> 4: Cost
>
> 5: Requirements and/or user stories (created with owner) <-- So many times we haven't had matching specs with the user

What else? .. if this exceeds two documents, its not gonna get done.

Comment: I think that "lazy colleagues" implies a more serious problem than the format of the initiation documentation.  They may be demonstrating the same lack of respect for you that you are demonstrating towards them.

Answer (score 1):

Add in a "Business Value" line... you have costs and need to balance this off against benefits.

I'd also retitle:

- "Cost" to read "Cost/Effort to Develop" to make sure that developer time is captured.
- "Business Case Description" to read "Business Need". Where I work if someone sees the former they can get their knickers in a knot when all you want to know is the "why".

You can also make the form a bit less onerous by turning items 1, 3 and 4 and any line on Business Value into checklists that give broad buckets (e.g. <20 hours effort, 20-40 hours effort, >40 hours effort).

But ultimately you are only going to get acceptance if there are consequences for non-use. Hopefully you'll have upper management support for this.